# How to asynchronously pass redshift query from lambda function?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I want to execute a group of copy commands in redshift from a lambda function where I copy around 100 GB of files from S3 to a table in redshift. I cannot use Redshift Data API for this (because I cannot have a secret arn for the cluster now and getting temporary credentials is also not ideal in my case).

I have tried using the psycopg2 library but as soon as the lambda function timeouts, the execution stops too.

Is there any way I can asynchronously pass the queries to redshift and when the lambda function timeouts, the query still keeps executing in redshift?

Comment: I gave you the answer [the last time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038660/how-to-make-the-copy-command-continue-its-run-in-redshift-even-after-the-lambda).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no.  This is fundamental to ODBC / JDBC connections - if the connection is dropped the transaction will be aborted.  I went so far a few years back as to have a small EC2 repeat Lambda SQL to Redshift so that Lambda could end w/o closing the connection. Worked great but having a server in the center of a server-less solution wasn’t quite right. You could go down this right if you like.

This is why Redshift Data API is a big step forward